# What function is on the graph?

Tags: functions

[image: The graph]

I need to know what function is on the graph.

And how do I determine the function name by its graph?

Comment: Looks like a [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) (with some discontinuities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? $|\arcsin(\sin(x))|$

Comment: This is the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l} x-2n & \text{for } x\in [2n,2n+1] \\ 1-(x-2n-1) & \text{for } x\in [2n+1,2(n+1)] \end{array} \right.  \quad \  n \in \mathbb N.$$

Or more generally
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l} a(x-b2n) & \text{for } x\in \big[b2n,b(2n+1)\big] \\ a\big(1-(x-b2n-1)\big) & \text{for } x\in \big[b(2n+1),2b(n+1)\big] \end{array} \right. \quad \  n \in \mathbb N.$$
where $a$ determines the height of the triangles and $b$ the length of the basis.

Answer (score 1):

You may like the followings :

- The graph of $y=||x|-1|$ is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%7Cx%7C-1%7C).
- The graph of $y=|||x|-1|-1|$ is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%7C%7Cx%7C-1%7C-1%7C).
- The graph of $y=||||x|-1|-1|-1|$ is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C%7C%7C%7Cx%7C-1%7C-1%7C-1%7C).

Answer (score 0):

You can never really determine a function by its graph... Because a graph is way to draw the function which is limited by the "real world".

Imagine your function being only defined on $Q$, you won't see that this is not defined on $R$ just by the graph.